# I could not delete polygon when marker is click

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to delete a polygon when my marker is being clicked,but i could not get how to make this work that the polygon will be deleted.I appreciate someone will help me to make this work.
This my demo in jsfiddle.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jemz24/BV3Js/30/)

here is my code it's not working.

```
var map;
var count = 0;
var polycolor = '#ED1B24';
var polyarray = [];
var marker;
var markers = [];
var path = new google.maps.MVCArray;

function initialize() {


    var initial = new google.maps.LatLng(53.199246241276875, -105.76864242553711);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: initial,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
        },
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    poly.setPaths(new google.maps.MVCArray([path]));

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
        addMarker(e);
        addPolygon(e);
    });
}

var deletepolygon = function (pt) {

    i = 0;
    var thepath = poly.getPath();

    thepath.forEach(function (ltlng) {
        i++;
        if ((ltlng.lat() + "," + ltlng.lng()) == pt) {
            path.removeAt(i);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I see no marker and no polygon in your demo. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please try again.i look at my demo,and i click the map,the marker show up.

Comment: did you click the map?it will add marker

Comment: Did you open your javascript console? http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/poly_edit.html

Comment: why is that if i will add 5 markers then i will delete the first marker,the ltlng in my if statement will be undefined

Comment: What about moving the `i++;` below the `if` statement?

Comment: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BV3Js/32/), seems to delete the marker and associated point in the polygon.  Is that what you want?  Or are you trying to delete the whole polygon on a right click or markers?

Comment: @geocodezip,thank you for your updated demo